# How to connect to a device BLE?

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to do a connection to a device with BLE. 
I need to connect to a specific device automatically. 
I don't understand how I can do to connect directly to a device. Let me explain better, at the moment I can scan and I get all the bluetooth devices. Instead, I would like to directly connect to a specific device.
- I should therefore select only one type of device
- Connect me directly

What do you think I can do?

*With this code i choose the name*

```
return (

        <View style={{borderBottomColor: 'lightgrey', borderBottomWidth: 1, alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', padding: 15}}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#888'}}>{`${peripheral.name}`}</Text>
                </View>
                  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
                    <Btn onPress={() => onConnect(peripheral)}>
                        {`Connect`}
                    </Btn>

                  </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
```

*With this code I do the scan*

```
return (

            <View style={{flex: 1 , paddingTop: Theme.navbarHeight }}>

                <StatusBar
                  /*  backgroundColor={Theme.color}*/
                  /*  barStyle="light-content" */
                />


                {
                    Object.keys(peripherals).length === 0 ? (
                        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                            { uiState === UiState.scanning && <ActivityIndicator size='large' color={Theme.color}/> }
                            <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize: 18, color: '#999'}}>
                                Nessun Risultato
                            </Text>
                            { uiState === UiState.idle && <Btn onPress={this._doScan}>Scansione</Btn> }
                        </View>
                    ) : (
                        <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'stretch' }}>
                            {
                                Object.keys(peripherals).map(key => peripherals[key]).map(
                                    peripheral => (
                                        <Peripheral
                                            key={peripheral.id}
                                            peripheral={peripheral}
                                            onConnect={onConnect}
                                        />
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        </ScrollView>
                    )
                }
            </View>
        )
    }

    _renderScanButton = () => {
        let {uiState} = this.state;
        if (uiState === UiState.scanning) {
            return <ActivityIndicator color='white'/>
        }
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._doScan}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white', width: 100, textAlign: 'right'}}>Scansione</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }


    _doScan = () => {
        if (this.state.uiState !== UiState.idle) {
            return;
        }

        this.setState({ uiState: UiState.scanning, peripherals: {} });
        BleManager.scan([], 5, true)
            .then(results => {
                console.log('Scansione in corso...');
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.setState({ uiState: UiState.idle })
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: What library are you using for BLE connection?

Comment: @AdamGold 'react-native-ble-manager'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `react-native-ble-manager`. According to their [docs](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager), you can connect to a peripheral using the `connect` method:

```
BleManager.connect('XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX')
  .then(() => {
    // Success code
    console.log('Connected');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Failure code
    console.log(error);
  });
```

You should get the peripheral UID from the scan method `results`:

```
BleManager.scan([], 5, true)
  .then(results => {
    // Success code
    console.log(results);
  });
```

I personally do not use the `react-native-ble-manager` package but the `react-native-ble-plx` package, but the process is pretty similar. Here's how I do it:

```
manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, async (error, device) => {
    console.log("scanning bluetooth...")

    if (device.name === "MY_DEVICE_NAME") {
        manager
            .connectToDevice(device.id, {
                autoconnect: true,
                timeout: BLUETOOTH_TIMEOUT
            })
        // ............
    }
})
```

Comment: first thanks for the reply! Instead of X, do I have to put the device name or MAC address?
Another question, if I need to connect to two devices at the same time can I use the same function?

Comment: You should put the address of the device. About multiple connections - I personally use the `react-native-ble-plx` package, don't know much about `react-native-ble-manager`.

Comment: Ok, i had see your edit post. So I should first scan (even without showing it to the user) and then use the results variable and pass it to the BleManager.connect function?

Comment: Not exactly. The `results` variable should contain all the peripherals. You should pick one and use its address.

Comment: About react-native-ble-plx can you read the notifications sent by the device?

Comment: I believe that you can.